# Switch views in empty application without storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm new to iOS development and am working on an app the interacts with a web service. I have a login view controller with it's respective NIB file, which controls the login page. And then I have a list view controller with it's respective NIB file, which displays a list of elements from the web service after logging in. When I created the application I created an empty application so right now I don't have a storyboard in my project.

I load the login view controller as the root view controller. After the login button is pressed and the credentials are validated I want to take users to the list view with the list view controller. After doing some research it seems that you need a storyboard to do this.

Do I actually need a storyboard to switch views and view controllers? If not how do I add a storyboard and use it with my current views, so I don't have to redo a whole view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a storyboard. However, it might be better to have the list view as the root view. then when the app loads check if they are logged in, if not present a login view modally (without animation if you want it to be instant) and then dismiss that when they log in. Do you have a tab bar or how are you navigating between sections of your app ?

Comment: You create a navigation controller as root view controller of your window. Then set login controller as root view controller of your navigation controller. If you want to show other controllers, just push them to navigation stack, or present them.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to discuss some case regarding your question.

**Case 1:** You have a navigation controller as the rootViewController of you window, and loginViewController as rootViewController of that navigation controller.

If login successful you can change the root view controller of navigation controller. For this you need to set a property in your AppDelegate. Like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navControl;
```

In AppDelegate.m file

```
self.navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
```

The assign a root view controller in navControl. And set it as a rootViewController of you window.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navControl;
```

And from your loginController if login successful then change the rootViewController of your navControl by creating an instance of AppDelegate.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.navControl.rootViewController = anotherViewController;
```

**Note:** Login is a special case. You don't want to come back to login page by pushing back button. So change the rootViewController of you navigation controller. But for other view you can just push ViewControllers.

**Case 2:** You don't have navControl as rootViewController. And if you want to just change the rootViewController of your window then you can do this:

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = anotherViewController;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1:first of all create UiWindow property in app delegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

2:In app delegate.m file create a universal variable of UINavigationController

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

3:customise your app delegate method like this, please note that import viewcontroller.h file in app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

   //suppose view controller is your login page 
    ViewController *viewController= [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    [navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:TRUE];



    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return YES;
}
```

I hope it will work.